# PowerShell pulling owner metadata from multiple files - failure

Tags: powershell, loops

With some help on another thread I have put together a script to pull filenames from a specific folder and search a larger database for the original files and identify their 'owner'. The current script is:

```
$desktopPath = [System.Environment]::GetFolderPath([System.Environment+SpecialFolder]::Desktop)
$images = $desktopPath + '\Get_Owner'
Get-ChildItem -Path $images | Select BaseName | Export-Csv $desktopPath`\Filenames.csv -NoTypeInformation
$serverPath = 'C:\Users\tuggleg\Desktop\Archive'
$files = Import-Csv -Path $desktopPath`\Filenames.csv

#import filenames and search server for filename and owner

ForEach ($fileName in $files.BaseName)
{
    Get-ChildItem -Path $serverPath -Filter "*$fileName*" -Recurse -ErrorAction 'SilentlyContinue' | 
           Select-Object -Property @{
            Name='Owner'
            Expression={(Get-Acl -Path $_.FullName).Owner}
          },'*' |
        Export-Csv -Path $desktopPath`\Owners.csv -NoTypeInformation
}
```

This script targets a folder where the user moves local files ($images) and pulls the filenames. It then searches a larger database ($serverPath) for the original file and pulls the owner. This script works with one filename but it does not 'loop' and continue working when multiple files are in the '$images' folder. I have tried the following and the script runs indefinitely but doesnt provide data in the output csv:

```
$desktopPath = [System.Environment]::GetFolderPath([System.Environment+SpecialFolder]::Desktop)
$images = $desktopPath + '\Get_Owner'
Get-ChildItem -Path $images | Select BaseName | Export-Csv $desktopPath`\Filenames.csv -NoTypeInformation
$serverPath = 'C:\Users\tuggleg\Desktop\Archive'
$files = Import-Csv -Path $desktopPath`\Filenames.csv

#import filenames and search server for filename and owner
#loop script
While($true) {

ForEach ($fileName in $files.BaseName)
{
    Get-ChildItem -Path $serverPath -Filter "*$fileName*" -Recurse -ErrorAction 'SilentlyContinue' | 
           Select-Object -Property @{
            Name='Owner'
            Expression={(Get-Acl -Path $_.FullName).Owner}
          },'*' |
        Export-Csv -Path $desktopPath`\Owners.csv -NoTypeInformation
}
}
```

Can anyone identify why the loop function breaks the script? Or better yet why the initial 'foreach' statement doesn't provide the owner for each file initially?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Far as I can tell, While($true) is running an infinite loop, and Export-Csv without the -NoClobber switch is overwriting the file for each iteration of the loop (== blank file once you run out of entries in $files).

Try adding -NoClobber (and/or -Append) switches & removing the While($true) loop - seems redundant as you've already got the ForEach.

Otherwise, you can collect the data & write it to csv once at the end, something like:

```
ForEach ($fileName in $files.BaseName)
{
 $data +=  Get-ChildItem -Path $serverPath -Filter "*$fileName*" -Recurse -ErrorAction 'SilentlyContinue' | 
           Select-Object -Property @{
            Name='Owner'
            Expression={(Get-Acl -Path $_.FullName).Owner}
          },'*'
}

$data | Export-Csv -Path $desktopPath`\Owners.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: I have never heard of -NoClobber! I went with -Append and no loop, and it works. Thanks so much @Gareth Lyons !

Comment: `-NoClobber` is supposed to error if the file already exists.  It's basically "fail if the file would be overwritten".  As far as I know it's synonymous with `-NoOverwrite`.  You need to specify `-Append` to actually append to a file.